# [JSOUP]why 1.6.x remove TD tags,Problems upgrading to 1.6.x

Tags: jsoup

```
System.out.println(Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("<td>123</td>").html());
```

**jsoup 1.5.2 OUTPUT:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>123</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

**jsoup 1.6.x (1.6.0 and 1.6.1) OUTPUT:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  123
 </body>
</html>
```

why 1.6.x remove `TD` tags?

how can I get jsoup 1.5.x OUTPUT in 1.6.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jsoup 1.6 I have rewritten the HTML parser to implement the [whatwg HTML spec](http://whatwg.org/html), which matches how browsers currently parse HTML.

The impact here is that in 1.5, a `<td>` was enough to auto-vivify a `<table>`; however browsers don't actually work that way, so in 1.6 you'll need to update your HTML input to introduce the `<table>` tag.

For example:

```java
System.out.println(
  Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("<table><td>123</td></table>").html());
```

will produce:

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>123</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note that the `<table><td>` gets normalised to `<table><tbody><tr><td>...`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer jonathan,in my project,I using Jsoup1.5.2 and xpath to parsing HTML,like:`<table><tr><td>name</td><td>age</td></tr><tr><td>name</td><td>age</td></tr>...</table>` ,I want get all `TR` fields,I using `doc.select("table tr")` and `for(Element tr:trs)` and `trDoc.select("td:ep(0)")` and `trDoc.select("td:ep(1)")` to get `name` and `age` ,is there a way to make my code compatible with 1.5.x and 1.6.x?